# View without subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to create a Mysql view but it as we know MySQL doesn't allow a view with a subquery.
How to create this without a subquery. Any idea?

```
SELECT yr.users_id, yr.Godi, Inc.Prihod, exp.Rashod
FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datum) Godi, users_id FROM income 
          UNION
          SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datum) Godi, users_id FROM expense
   ) yr
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT sum(insum) as Prihod,
                  YEAR(datum) as Godi,
                  users_id 
                  FROM income
            GROUP BY YEAR(datum), users_id
       ) inc ON yr.users_id = inc.users_id AND yr.Godi = inc.Godi 
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT sum(amount) as Rashod,
                  YEAR(datum) as God,
                  users_id 
             FROM expense
             GROUP BY YEAR(datum), users_id
   ) exp ON yr.users_id = exp.users_id AND yr.Godi = exp.God
```

Comment: Creating innerquery as another view would do?

Comment: You need to create a view for each sub query and then create a view by joining these views

Comment: M Khalid Junaid - how to do that?